# Child foreach not looping as intended in Partial using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, viewmodel, partials

I have a List of Recipes and each Recipe has a number of RecipeLines, I want to loop Each Recipe with it's corresponding Recipe Lines foreach Looping inside of the parent Recipe foreach.

Recipe Class

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class Recipe
        {
            public int RecipeID { get; set; }
            public string RecipeName { get; set; }
            public string RecipeInstructions { get; set; }

            public virtual List<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

RecipeLine Class

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class RecipeLine
        {
            public int RecipeLineID { get; set; }
            public float Quantity { get; set; }

            public int MeasurementID { get; set; }
            public int RecipeID { get; set; }
            public int IngredientID { get; set; }

            public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
            public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
            public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

No need to list the Ingredient and Measurement Class, but they are structured fine.

Now let's look at the ViewModel

```
    namespace XXX.ViewModels
    {
        public class RecipeLineViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And the PartialsController

```
    namespace XXX.Controllers
    {

        public class PartialsController : Controller
        {
            private XXXDb db = new XXXDb();

            public ActionResult RecipeList()
            {
                RecipeLineViewModel viewModel;

                viewModel = new RecipeLineViewModel();
                viewModel.Recipes = db.Recipes.ToList();
                viewModel.RecipeLines = db.RecipeLines.Include(r => 
                r.Measurement).Include(r => r.Ingredient);

                return PartialView("_RecipeList", viewModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the partial view is Views > Partials > __RecipeList.cshtml

RecipeList Partial View

```
    @model XXX.ViewModels.RecipeLineViewModel

    @foreach (Recipe recipe in Model.Recipes) 
        {
        <div>@recipe.RecipeName</div>
        <div>@recipe.RecipeInstructions</div>

            foreach (RecipeLine recipeLines in Model.RecipeLines)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                        @recipeLines.Quantity @recipeLines.Measurement.MeasurementEn 
                        @recipeLines.Ingredient.IngredientNameEn
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

        }
    }
```

(I printed the RecipeID at the end of each recipeLine to show that each recipe is repeating out Recipe Lines for RecipeID = 1 and not their Lines related to their own RecipeID. I'm a newbie to this stuff, I'm assuming that somewhere I should be telling the Recipe Lines about the RecipeID they should be looping for????

Here is the result I'm getting:

[image: Parent/Child Loop Result:]

Comment: if your Recipe class has a RecipeLines collection why do you have one in your ViewModel? Your inner loop should be printing `recipe.RecipeLines`...

Comment: I'm trying to fix with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a where Linq clause to foreach.

```
   @foreach (Recipe recipe in Model.Recipes) 
            {
            <div>@recipe.RecipeName</div>
            <div>@recipe.RecipeInstructions</div>

                foreach (RecipeLine recipeLines in Model.RecipeLines.Where(rl => rl.RecipeID == recipe.RecipeID))
                {
```

Upd:
Also you can definently include RecipeLine stuff in Recipes  and you won't need RecipeLine Collection at all! Just loop through recipe.RecipeLines

Something like this:

```
viewModel.Recipes = db.Recipes.Include("RecipeLine").Include("RecipeLine.Measurement").
                .Include("RecipeLine.Ingredient");
```

Comment: I appreciate your code sample, This is exactly what I was trying to do but my syntax was off. Thanks for your time! I marked your as the correct answer because of the code sample that worked (cut&paste).

Comment: Since I 1up you and selected it as the right answer you got 25 points! Now you can comment on peoples answers because I put you over 50 points! I think you can upload images now too because you are over 40 points. Good job, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the alternate. Is there any optimization in that example? Does it result in less work on the server/database? I do like the way I have it, because I'm just learning Partials and View Models and it's very verbose which makes it easy for me to read and understand, but I like learning shortcuts too that require less code and efficiency in terms of round trips to database, server, etc..

Comment: Well, thanks) The first approach is slower, because, if you have for example 10 recipes and 100 recipeLines it will loop through all 100 recipelines 10 times ( for each where ) Each time looking for specific RecipeID. And in second approach you only get a collection of recipelines for each recipe, and you won't need to do "where" 10 times and you won't need IEnumerable<RecipieLine> in your ViewModel

Comment: And by the way in your current code .Include(r => r.Recipe) is redundant.

Comment: `aershov` I just tried to set it up the way that you explained in your second option. But I had some problems with syntax. Is there any way you could edit my question to show what you mean. I have no problem when I remove the IEnumerable from the modelview, but I have a problem implementing the syntax for the foreach. Or if you could just copy my questions code and replace your answer with the correction? Only if you have the time though. I'd like to figure that out so I am not roundtripping so many times.

Comment: @EricB - I have added an example of what I believe aershov is referring to in my example.  Not to detract from his answer but for completeness, plus I prefer not to edit other peoples answers.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Recipie` model you have have a `List<RecipieLine>` property which one would assume is to maintain one or more `RecipieLine` model objects.  In your `RecipieLineViewModel` you have two separate `IEnumerable` collections exposing your `Recipie` and `RecipieLine` objects.

In your actual view, you are iterating over your `Recipie` collection:

```
@foreach (Recipe recipe in Model.Recipes)
```

Looks good, however, the following line is your issue:

```
foreach (RecipeLine recipeLines in Model.RecipeLines)
```

This enumerates over the `RecipieLine` model objects stored in your `RecipieLineViewModel` `RecipieLine` collection, however, it currently has no way of knowing which `Recipie` you are currently enumerating in your outer `foreach`.

You either want to provide a `where` LINQ clause of some sort using the data available to you from the current `Recipie` object enumeration, or alter the inner `foreach` to use the current `Recipie` enumeration rather than the `Model`.

**Update**

For completeness, here is an example of how to use the current `Recipe` object enumeration to access its associated `RecipieLine`s:

```
@forech (var recipie in Model.Recipies)
{
    <div>@recipe.RecipeName</div>
    <div>@recipe.RecipeInstructions</div>
    foreach (var recipieLine in recipie.RecipieLines)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                // Do something with recipieLine here
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The above would be my preferred method as it is more efficient that performing a LINQ query each enumeration, and removes the `IEnumerable<RecipieLine>` from your `ViewModel` which is effectively duplicate code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I selected the answer above as the correct answer because he provided a code sample that worked; however, I gave your answer a 1up because of the explanation which would have led to the right answer, plus you give an alternative option that I will look into. I appreciate the time you took to reply!

Comment: @EricB - Glad you got your answer, that is priority, the upvote is appreciated though.  The alternate solution of using the current `Recipie` enumeration would allow you to remove the duplicated `IEnumerable<RecipieLine>` collection in your `ViewModel`. It would be my preferred method.

Comment: Second foreach:    
 foreach (RecipeLine recipeLine in recipe.RecipeLines)

Comment: @aershov - I think you meant to post your comment above buddy.

Comment: Thanks Im pouring over this now. YOu guys are a huge help. I really want to know the correct way.